# FloatProperty not precise (bug?)

Tags: properties

So I assigned a floatproperty inside my script.
As I moved along I noticed differences that was unexplainable. SO I started to check the properties and how the system take care of them.

Result is

```
  lenght1: FloatProperty(
        name="Lenght1", unit="LENGTH", default=40.0 / 1000,
    )
```

Prints as

[image]

As you can see, the property that is 40 became 39.9xx?

Any idea if this is a bug?

Since I do a lot of calculations this becomes an issue and some results get off by more then 1 which is a no no

Comment: A solution for this is to actually store strings instead of float values, and parse them every time you want to do calculations. (eg `length1: bpy.props.StringProperty()` and then `length1 = "40.0"`) This is a very well know problem with computer calculations and optimization.

Comment: @Gorgious  Thanks for pointing this out. This indeed makes the precision a lot better.

Answer (score 3):

It is not a bug. Floating point numbers are only accurate to about 8 decimals in Blender because it uses CPU single precision internally. Depending on what you mean by a lot you might want to investigate numpy which uses double precision internally.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. May I ask, As you see I made the property 40.0 and not 39.9
So what makes it change from my initial 40 to 39.9?

Comment: It's not 39.9 but 39.999999... which in 8 bit precision is equal to 40

Comment: Sorry I didn't reply sooner. I've been traveling.  @Gorgious is right.  It's a quirk of how floating point numbers are generated that they often end up being represented with repeating-last-digit representations.